# How to properly design a reliable acknowledgment mechanism using Parse Server?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, parse-platform

I am working on an app where this scenario will occur

1. Parse server sends a silent push notification to tell the app to wake up and pull the new data
2. App sends the server a request to get new data and the server responds
3. Server doesn't know if the data was received by the app.....

How to solve this last step? How to make sure that the app gets a chance to acknowledge the receipt of data?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do in this way:

1. When app send to server the request of new data, send an id code too
2. Server store this id
3. When app ends the data receiving, send to server a receive ok message with id.
4. When the server receive the "receive ok" message from an app, delete from its list the id of the app.

In this way the server knows how many app ask the data transfer an how many app receive data successfully.

The app id, for the data transfer, can change between any transfer session .

Comment: This will miss some cases; the app will receive data but be unable to report "receive ok" to the server. It might be good enough though.

Comment: What other ways can we go about this? Web sockets? other protocols?

Comment: I am already using Http request, does this mean that acknowledgment is build in? data resent automatically?

Comment: No. You implement the acknoweledgment. But, i don't understand, your application can communicate with the server but it can't sent "receive ok"?

Comment: The problem is I am using Parse Server and cloud code...When the app contacts the server and the server responds the session is closed and there is no simple way for the app to acknowledge this last transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to solve the [Two Generals Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem) is unlikely to be productive. Instead consider how you might design a system which can tolerate failure.

Your push notification may never be delivered. Can your app check for new data when brought to the foreground or otherwise have some backup so that it remains useful?

After receiving a push notification your app might not be able to send a request to load this data. Can you rely on the next notification or treat this like a missing notification and still allow your app to be useful?

After requesting data your app may never receive the response. Again how might you make sure the app remains useful to its users? If timely delivery of this data is not critical maybe you can rely on retry mechanisms. If it is critical maybe you need some way to warn the user when you appear to be out of date.

What solution makes sense for you really depends on what your app is doing and why it needs this data.

Comment: If the app doesn't pull data after the server sent a notification, the server will try again after a predefined time. It is not that I am not designing a system that is not tolerating failure, I just want to make sure I design an acknowledgement mechanism so that I can detect if the data was not sent and take further action.

Comment: The server can detect if the data was requested but not reliably determine if it was received. The client can detect if data was received but cannot know if it was never notified that new data is available.

Comment: How would you solve this if I told you that time delivery is somewhat critical, you can think of this app as being a chat app, so a few seconds delay might not be a problem.

Comment: Sounds like the risk is almost entirely on the notification delivery side where you also have the least control. Once you receive the notification the app can make a best effort to fetch data and indicate failure to the user (some "there's a message for you I can't retrieve" message). The server can never be certain if delivery failed but can be certain about some successful deliveries. I'd probably still use notifications for delivery just be mindful that they can be late or dropped and maybe track time from notification sent to messaged fetched by the app.